# ezknit (package ezknitr) does not parse YAML header

Tags: r, yaml, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to knit a `.Rmd` file using R package `ezknitr`. The problem is, that the YAML header appears **not** to get parsed/ is ignored by `ezknitr`.

For that, I have created some dummy .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "dummy"
author: "Sebastian Sauer"
date: "28 Juli 2016"
output: html_document
---

TEST - ezknit.
```

I saved this file as, say, `dummy.Rmd`.

Then I knitted it like this:

```
ezknit(file = "analysis/dummy.Rmd")
```

The resulting .html file does **not** show a title or other meta data.

However, knitting with normal knit (eg "knit button" in RStudio) does produce a html page **with** title etc.

I would like `ezknit` to produce a html page where the YAML header is parsed.

Thanks for any ideas.

UPDATE 1:

I have tried to knit this file:

````
---
title: "dummy"
author: "me"
date: "28 Juli 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r}

knitr::opts_knit$set(base.dir = "..", output.dir = "../reports")
```

```{r}
plot(mtcars$hp)
```
````

But it failed with pandoc error 67.

The `reports` folder is located one step up the path, but apparently not found.

*However*, I was able to get a halfway solution: Just let the output html be rendered in the script file (ie., working directory); no specification of `output.dir` in `opts_knit`. This is far from perfect, but at least it compiles.

`sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ezknitr_0.4     leaps_2.9       dplyr_0.5.0     tibble_1.1      caret_6.0-70   
 [6] ggplot2_2.1.0   tidyr_0.5.1     knitr_1.13.6    readr_0.2.2     mice_2.25      
[11] Rcpp_0.12.5     magrittr_1.5    pscl_1.4.9      lattice_0.20-33 MASS_7.3-45    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] reshape2_1.4.1      splines_3.3.1       colorspace_1.2-6    htmltools_0.3.5    
 [5] stats4_3.3.1        yaml_2.1.13         mgcv_1.8-12         survival_2.39-5    
 [9] R.oo_1.20.0         e1071_1.6-7         nloptr_1.0.4        DBI_0.4-1          
[13] R.utils_2.3.0       foreach_1.4.3       plyr_1.8.4          stringr_1.0.0.9000 
[17] MatrixModels_0.4-1  munsell_0.4.3       gtable_0.2.0        R.methodsS3_1.7.1  
[21] codetools_0.2-14    evaluate_0.9        SparseM_1.7         quantreg_5.26      
[25] pbkrtest_0.4-6      parallel_3.3.1      class_7.3-14        markdown_0.7.7     
[29] highr_0.6           scales_0.4.0        formatR_1.4         mime_0.5           
[33] lme4_1.1-12         digest_0.6.9        stringi_1.1.1       grid_3.3.1         
[37] tools_3.3.1         lazyeval_0.2.0.9000 car_2.1-2           Matrix_1.2-6       
[41] assertthat_0.1      minqa_1.2.4         rmarkdown_1.0       iterators_1.0.8    
[45] R6_2.1.2            rpart_4.1-10        nnet_7.3-12         nlme_3.1-128       
[49] compiler_3.3.1
```

Comment: seems like a bug that you should report to the package creator. I didn't know about ezknitr but it looks like what it does can easily be accomplished in knitr with a first chunk that sets global knitr options `library(knitr) ; opts_knit$set(base.dir = "..", output.dir = "../output")`

Comment: unfortunately, that did not work for me; see my edit above for details.

Comment: Agree with @scoa, you could also try using `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = here::here())` if in an **R Project**. But do load data in a new chunk after this command executes.